# Nestle Cream "Ashta"

Tags: cream

I was in the middle east for a few weeks a few months ago. Anyways, I was introduced to the following Nestle cream:

[image: ashta picture]

It didn't really taste like the cream I'm used to here in North America.

- Have any of you tried this before?
- Can I make it at home?

Comment: Which taste did it have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My family really liked this after they had it on a trip to Oman.

I've never tried to make it, but it can be purchased for not much money at indian/middle eastern food stores. It is a bit hard to find, but in any decent city there should be something. I get mine from a little halal market I also get my lamb and goat from.

It makes excellent mango smoothies.

Comment: I live in the middle of nowhere ruraltown

Answer (score 3):

I haven't had it. As to making it at home: that would be a recipe, which normally is outside of this site's scope. I'll give you 2 links, though, from which I'll try to distill a general description of 'Ashta type cream'.

This type of cream contains:

- Milk, Milk-and-cream or powdered milk
- (corn)starch
- orange blossom or rose water
- sugar.

Source links:

http://arabicbites.blogspot.com/2007/06/ataif-bil-ashta.html
http://www.tasteofbeirut.com/2010/05/lebanese-cream-ashta/